# Java Memory Used

Tags: java, memory, hashmap, jvm

I am trying to find out the amount of RAM consumed by a map. So, I did the following;-

```
Map<String,Double> cr = crPair.collectAsMap(); // 200+ entries
System.out.println("free memory = " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
Map<String,Double> gen = new HashMap<>();
gen.putAll(cr);
System.out.println("free memory = " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
```

The response I got was:-

```
free memory = 940714880
free memory = 940714880
```

I basically wanted to see how many entries my map can support before exceeding a particular threshold. This however implies no extra bytes. What am I missing? Also, can anyone give a rough estimate as to the amount of space taken by a hashmap(order of 1000 entries).

Comment: http://java-performance.info/memory-consumption-of-java-data-types-2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Runtime.freeMemory` returns only a rough estimate. It's not suitable for measuring memory occupied by a given object.

You may use [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) with built-in `-prof gc` profiler to get much more accurate estimate. Here is a sample benchmark to measure space occupied by a HashMap (not counting the memory used by keys and values themselves).

```
package bench;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class MapSizeBench {
    @Param({"10", "100", "1000", "10000", "100000"})
    int size;

    Map<String, Double> map;

    @Setup
    public void setup() {
        map = IntStream.range(0, size).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                n -> "key" + n,
                n -> ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble()));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public Map<String, Double> hashMap() {
        return new HashMap<>(map);
    }
}
```

`gc.alloc.rate.norm` value will show the number of bytes allocated while executing the method marked with `@Benchmark` annotation:

```
Benchmark                                  (size)  Mode  Cnt        Score   Error  Units
MapSizeBench.hashMap:·gc.alloc.rate.norm       10  avgt    5      448,000 ± 0,001   B/op
MapSizeBench.hashMap:·gc.alloc.rate.norm      100  avgt    5     4288,001 ± 0,001   B/op
MapSizeBench.hashMap:·gc.alloc.rate.norm     1000  avgt    5    40256,009 ± 0,002   B/op
MapSizeBench.hashMap:·gc.alloc.rate.norm    10000  avgt    5   385640,093 ± 0,017   B/op
MapSizeBench.hashMap:·gc.alloc.rate.norm   100000  avgt    5  4248681,606 ± 0,329   B/op
```

That is, a HashMap of 1000 elements will take about 40KB on JDK 8 x64 with CompressedOops enabled.

Alternatively, you may take full heap dump:

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap.hprof <pid>
```

and analyze it in [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/). This tool can show you the memory occupied by any given object or a graph of objects.

Answer (score 3):

First there is a specialized tool for measuring these things called [JOL](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjf57Lfls3XAhXHKlAKHetaAzQQFggjMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fopenjdk.java.net%2Fprojects%2Fcode-tools%2Fjol%2F&usg=AOvVaw3tESofg6SLxFpgO6q34A4Y).

Playing with is quite easy and it will give you some very good input, for example:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(8);
map.put("key", "value");

for (int i = 0; i < 2_000; i++) {
    map.put("key" + i, "value");
}

System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(map).totalSize());
```

Also [this answer is very much related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41871608/1059372)