# Memory Consumption in Collections

Tags: java, memory-management, collections

Hi Recently at an interview, I was asked that I have a Hashmap, an ArrayList and a Hashset. They each contain same 10 user defined objects (eg: Employee class object). Which will consume more heap space and why ?

I gave answer as Hashmap as it stores both key-value pair. But then Hashset also internally uses hashmap to store the values.

1. Can somebody please give ans with reason.
2. Is there any tool or eclipse plugin I can use to check this myself ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Any text editor allows looking at the code of HashMap and HashSet, which come with the JDK.

Comment: @JBNizet but hashset also stores as key-value pair (though value in this case is constant). So it should have been hashmap only. Right ? as i can have any value which is bigger than the default PRESENT value of hashset.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "it should have been hashmap only", or by "i can have any value which is bigger than the default PRESENT value".

Comment: What I meant was suppose in the hash map I have a string as value which takes 300 bytes. Now in the hash set PRESENT is a dummy value (let its size be 100 bytes). So the size of PRESENT will be constant every time but the size of value in the hash map can vary. I hope I'm clear this time around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are counting both the memory required by the container and the memory required by the "10 user defined objects" then you are correct.

`HashMap` would occupy more space.

Even though `HashSet` is backed by a `HashMap`, the value it stores in all its entries is a reference to the same dummy instance.

Therefore a `HashSet` would require 10 key references + 10 value references + 10 elements + 1 dummy instance.

On the other hand a `HashMap` would require 10 key references + 10 value references + 10 key instances + 10 value instances (assuming the "10 user defined objects" are stored as values).

Of course, to be more accurate you have to also count the size of the array holding the `HashMap`s buckets, but that would be the same in both the `HashMap` and `HashSet`, since they contain the same number of elements.

Note that, as JB Nizet commented, if the key of the `HashMap` is a property of the "10 user defined objects", the "10 key instances" do not require additional memory (since they already exist), so both the `HashMap` and `HashSet` would require the same amount of memory for storing the 10 objects, with the `HashSet` actually requiring a bit more memory, since it holds a reference to a `HashMap`.

The `ArrayList` should take less memory than both the `HashSet` and `HashMap`, since the backing array of an `ArrayList` has a default initial length of 10 (which is enough to store the 10 objects), while the array of the buckets of a `HashMap` has a default initial length of 16 (also enough to store the 10 objects, assuming we use the default load factor of 0.75).

Comment: Given that they only said that employees were stored in the map, one can assume (I did) that the key was a field of this employee (his name or ID, for example). In that case, there is no additional 10 key instances, and the HashMap and the HashSet consume the same amount of memory (actually a bit more for the HashSet, since it needs a reference to its backing HashMap).

Comment: @JBNizet If the key is a property of the "user defined object" then you are correct. Good point

Comment: Since the question is about ten elements, I would not expect any capacity increase operation at all. `ArrayList`’s default capacity is ten, so all elements fit in, `HashMap`’s default capacity is `16` with a load factor of `0.75`, so it will accept up to twelve elements before increasing the capacity. Of course, `16` still is larger than `10`, so `HashMap`/`HashSet` have a bigger capacity in this case (and in every other case as `HashMap` doubles the capacity when needed whereas `ArrayList` uses factor 1.5).

Comment: @Eran I like this answer, but I really wanted proof, so I added a small augment to yours...

Answer (score 2):

I found this very interesting and while I do agree with Eran here, proper proof is required. I am using [JOL for the measuring](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/).

For the purpose of the example I created an `Employee` with two fields `String name` and `int age`.

So let's see what is going on:

```
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Employee(22, "a"));

System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(list).totalSize()); //152 bytes
```

Let's see where this space is coming from:

```
12 bytes ArrayList headers
4 bytes int modCount in ArrayList
4 bytes int size in ArrayList
4 bytes for the reference "elementData" in ArrayList

12 bytes for the Employee headers
4 bytes int age Employee
4 bytes for String name reference 
4 bytes padding (objects are 8 bytes aligned)

12 bytes for the String "a" headers
4 bytes for the char[] reference 
4 bytes for the int hash
4 bytes padding

12 bytes for the new char[] { 'a' }
4 bytes the size of the array (store in headers)
2 bytes for char 'a'
6 bytes padding

40 bytes for the 10 references in elementData array
12 bytes for it's headers (arrays are Objects)
4 bytes for the size (arrays have a size)
```

For the sake of the example I am going to add 2 employees next and keep the explanation about size shorter:

```
HashMap<Employee, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(new Employee(22, "a"), 100);
map.put(new Employee(23, "b"), 200);

System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(map).toFootprint());
```

You will get an output like that:

```
  COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
     2        24        48   [C
     1        80        80   [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node;
     2        16        32   java.lang.Integer
     2        24        48   java.lang.String
     1        48        48   java.util.HashMap
     2        32        64   java.util.HashMap$Node
     2        24        48   org.erabii.tenelemdiff.Test$Employee
    12                 368   (total)
```

Total size is `368` bytes. Now let's put them into a `HashSet`:

```
HashSet<Employee> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(new Employee(22, "a"));
set.add(new Employee(23, "b"));

System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(set).totalSize()); // 368 bytes
```

---

You can see that a `HashSet` and a `HashMap` has the same size for this specific scenario. Things can get even trickier if you add more then 12 entries (when by default a `HashMap` re-sizes) and *potentially* will change it's buckets from `LinkedNode`s to `TreeNode`s and the difference [is quite significant, read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41871608/1059372). A `Node` is 32 bytes, while a `TreeNode` is 56 bytes.

Comment: Nice analysis! However, isn't the 368 bytes result you got for both `HashSet` and `HashMap` a coincidence? After all, your `HashMap` example has two additional  `Integer` instances, but on the other hand, the `HashSet` example has the additional `private transient HashMap<E,Object> map;` reference (and the overhead of having both a `HashSet` and a `HashMap` instance). Do you get the same result if you put/add 10 entries/elements?

Comment: @Eran good catch - I chose these values *on purpose* to produce the same bytes. And yes, the values, will be different for 10 entries